# Moving min/max/close buttons back to right hand side for full screen windows

Tags: unity, 11.04, compiz

How do I move the minimuze/maximise/close buttons to the right hand under Unity, for maximised windows?

I've used `gconf-editor` to change */apps/metacity/general/button_layout* to move them to the right hand side for windows which aren't maximised, but once maximised it moves back to the left hand side.

Comment: This question should not have been closed. It is exactly what I want to know.

Comment: It's impossible right now. Our only chance is to vote on [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1622043).

Answer (score 5):

just install and use ubuntu tweak ( http://ubuntu-tweak.com)

in ubuntu tweak goto the desktop->window manager setting section on the left.
then goto windows titlebar button layout and click the place right choice offered to you.

to install ubuntu tweak just go to the website and download the .deb file
and open it with ubuntu software center ..
it usually is installed in applications->system tools->ubuntu tweak

good luck

Comment: Thanks - point your elbow at the ceiling and pat yourself on the back!

Comment: I have done this in the past, but it doesn't work for me now (cannot find such an option in Ubuntu Tweak, using Ubuntu 14.04.3).

Comment: Ubuntu Tweak 0.0.7 [no longer has an option to change the location of the window controls](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-tweak-tool/+bug/1309942/comments/8). It's also no longer maintained.

Comment: It worked quite well 5 years ago :)
What's the point you're trying to make here ?

Answer (score 1):

The way unity works, the buttons appear on the left side, and it's coded to work that way only. You would have to write a bug report about this (I would support it).