# How do I move the Unity title bar buttons to the right side?

Tags: unity, panel

Can I put the title bar buttons in Unity on the right side *somehow*, or is that impossible?

Comment: You can move buttons of the unmaximized Windows to the right side with command gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout ':minimize,maximize,close' But Window buttons in panel for maximized windows don't respect org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences like normal windows do :( See bug [1072755](http://launchpad.net/bugs/1072755) for more info.

Comment: It's impossible right now. Our only chance is to vote on [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1622043).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do this using gsettings:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout ':minimize,maximize,close'
```

or gconf-editor which has more complicated instructions listed at:

http://handytutorial.com/move-window-buttons-to-right-in-ubuntu-12-10-12-04/

Comment: This doesn't work on 15.10!

Comment: Didn't do anything in 16.04. Do I need to log back in or something?

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, hopefully this will save someone else who is googling this issue the time.. Ubuntu Tweak nor gconf-editor will fix this problem. Seems to be a known issue with Unity. Seems there is no solution in the works either.

Closest thing I saw to a somewhat resolution. Seems to be pawned off on Unity:

- [bug 772212](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/772212)
- [fossplanet discussion](http://fossplanet.com/f10/%5Bbug-772212%5D-%5Bnew%5D-unity-__-moving-min-max-close-buttons-back-toright-hand-side-full-screen-windows-142150/)

Answer (score 2):

impossible as of now, and most likely it will stay impossible, unless someone wants to write a nasty hack.

Comment: Not anymore: see http://handytutorial.com/move-window-buttons-to-right-in-ubuntu-12-10-12-04/

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Tweak can do that for you in the Windows Management Settings. You can get it at http://ubuntu-tweak.com

Comment: partially true, if using metacity then YES if using emerald then NO , you have to set it from the emerald manager

Comment: Ubuntu Tweak 0.0.7 [no longer has an option to change the location of the window controls](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-tweak-tool/+bug/1309942/comments/8). It's also no longer maintained.

Answer (score 0):

[Moving min/max/close buttons back to right hand side for full screen windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25901/moving-min-max-close-buttons-back-to-right-hand-side-for-full-screen-windows)

Look the last post.
I could help you...

Answer (score 0):

Configuration Editor > Apps > Metacity > General > Button layout edit key to minimize, maximize, close

Log out or type `nautilus -q` in a terminal to restart Nautilus. Also while, you're there, may as well check the boxes for Metacity to be composite manger and effects