# How can I move the close/minimize/maximize buttons on the unity panel?

Tags: unity, configuration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I move the Unity title bar buttons to the right side?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44187/how-do-i-move-the-unity-title-bar-buttons-to-the-right-side)

I followed [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/config-desktop/C/window-button-order.html) to move the minimize/maximize/close buttons no the upper right of a window. They involve running `gconf-editor` and changing the order of the buttons. Its pretty annoying though that the unity panel keeps the buttons on the upper left, so the effect is when the window is maximized, the buttons show on the upper left but when the window is not maximized they show up in the upper right.

Is there any way to make the Unity panel consistent with the `gconf-editor` button settings?