# Add a Dash / Lens to Gnome Flashback (14.04)

Tags: gnome, unity-dash

I've installed Gnome Flashback (Compiz) because I need window control buttons on the right hand side.

Really, the only thing I'm missing is a dash / lens.  I'd like to be able to press the "Super" key, type "firef", hit enter, and have Firefox launch.

Is there any plugin I can use?

I [read that Unity 2D could do this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158050/unity-like-dashboard-for-gnome-fallback) - but it doesn't seem to be included in 14.04

Comment: You can [set Unity to put the window buttons on the right side](http://askubuntu.com/questions/44187/how-do-i-move-the-unity-title-bar-buttons-to-the-right-side) anyway... If you want a Dash just use normal Gnome 3...

Comment: You cannot as of 14.04 http://askubuntu.com/questions/174292/how-can-i-move-all-the-window-controls-to-the-right-or-left

Answer (score 0):

Unity != GNOME Flashback.

You can try to use Alt+F2 to open run dialog. It will allow you to launch firefox by typing name and hitting enter.