# How I can get Unity interface on MS Windows system?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft, windows-xp

I have Ubuntu installed as primary system on my computer. So, I'm pretty used to the Unity, mainly indicators and dash, launcher is set on always visible in Compiz settings, and I'm waiting till somebody figures out how to get it to bottom of the screen as I would prefer it this way, but I'm fine with how it is now, I think the gobal menu should be selectable feature, and through [Other tip](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25901/moving-min-max-close-buttons-back-to-right-hand-side-for-full-screen-windows) I had changed the position of window buttons. It also has significant eye-candy. However, I'm forced to have Windows XP and 7 system installed alongside, as Wine API isn't advanced enough to run some applications without open-source alternative, and, mainly, games my relatives play, at the time of asking (11/8). So, when I have to use Windows, I'm quite lost. However, if I had Unity also on both Windows system, it would improve consistency, and I could use what I know from Ubuntu as my primary system! My relatives also admire Unity, so, it would definitively help me. Thanks!

Comment: Offtopic - not an Ubuntu question

Answer (score 3):

It isn't possible. Appindicators are platform independent, though, so you could implement a panel for Windows that supported them, and then applications using them would just work. But that is a fair amount of work.

Perhaps it might be possible to port Unity-2D to Windows, but I don't think there's any proposal or will to do that.